# Add custom props to this.props.children in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component which accepts children. Let's say;

```
<Toolbar><div>C1</div><div>C2</div></Toolbar>
```

When I print children using `{children}` inside of `Toolbar`, I can see them. However, I need to add/manupilate some props, so I want to iterate over them (like other arrays.map). However, when I try to use `children.map` I get following error.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in 
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

How can I achive this?

Thank you!

Edit; I mean something like;

```
{children.map((Child,index)=> <Child {...newProps}/>)}
```

Comment: assuming children is an array, you'll also potentially want to add a key property to each item - but I would check that all your components are exported properly out of their file they are defined in, and importing it in properly. I would want to see how you defined that as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would make use of `React.Children.map` and then `React.cloneElement` to return the children after adding new props

```
    {React.Children.map(children, child => {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {
                    ...newProps
                });
            })}
```